# Mockito 2 Mocks Returning Stream - No suitable method found

Tags: java, generics, mocking, mockito, java-stream

I have a function in the implementation with the signature

```
Class Foo {
    Stream<? extends Bar> doSomething() { ... }
}
```

However, in my tests when I did something like

```
when(foo.doSomething()).thenReturn(Stream.of(bar1, bar2));
```

I got the following compilation error:

```
no suitable method found for thenReturn(java.util.stream.Stream<Bar>)
method org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(java.util.stream.Stream<capture#1 of ? extends Bar>,java.util.stream.Stream<capture#1 of ? extends Bar>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: capture#1 of ? extends Bar
          lower bounds: Bar)
```

Unfortunately, using `Stream.<? extends Foo>(bar1, bar2)` didn't work either. Looking for a fix.

Thanks!

---

EDIT:
FYI this worked when I was using Mockito 1.10.x, it stopped working once i updated Mockito to 2.28.x

Comment: What types do `bar1` and `bar2` have?

Comment: @Turing85 they're both of a subtype of Bar.

Comment: Have you tried `Stream.<Bar>of(bar1, bar2)`?

Comment: Yep - same issue

Comment: Hm. We need a [MRE]. The local tests I did yielded no such compiler error as the one describet in the post.

Comment: A declaration something like *`@Mock Stream< Bar > mockBarStream…`* and then a *`…when( foo.doSomething( ) ).thenReturn( mockBarStream )…`* in the actual test, seems like it should work. Did you try that?

Comment: „*…i updated Mockito to 2.28.x…*“ . – @ddolce — [*Mockito 2.28.x is more than 1.5 years old*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.28.2). The latest and greatest is [*v3.5.1*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.11). Why are you constrained to such an *old* version?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The only possible workaround is using `OngoingStubbing<T> thenAnswer(Answer<?> answer)` which expects any parametrized type (`Answer<?>`):

- expanded:

  ```
  Stream<? extends Bar> stream = Stream.of(new Buzz(), new Buzz(), new Buzz());
  ```

  ```
  Mockito.when(foo.doSomething()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Stream<? extends Bar>>() {
      @Override
      public Stream<? extends Bar> answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
          return stream;
      }
  });
  ```
- short version:

  ```
  Mockito.when(foo.doSomething()).thenAnswer(invocation -> stream);
  ```

**Explanation**

The method `OngoingStubbing<T> thenReturn(T value)` expects in case of mocking `Stream<? extends Bar> doSomething()` method the `Stream<? extends Bar>` type at the input. Passing `Stream.of(bar1, bar2))` doesn't guarantee the parameters fit the same parametrized type.

Let `Buzz` extend `Bar`:

```
Stream<? extends Bar> stream = Stream.of(new Buzz(), new Buzz(), new Buzz());
Mockito.when(foo.doSomething()).thenReturn(stream);
```

The very same issue is reproducible with the following code:

```
static class FluentFactory {
    static <T> Fluent<T> fluent(T methodCall) { return new Fluent<>(); }
}
    
static class Fluent<T>  {
    Fluent<T> first(T t) { return new Fluent<>(); }
}
```

```
Stream<? extends Bar> stream = Stream.of(new Buzz(), new Buzz(), new Buzz());
FluentFactory.fluent(foo.doSomething()).first(stream);
```

> Error:(xx, yy) java: incompatible types: java.util.stream.Stream<capture#1 of ? extends com.mycompany.Foo> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Stream<capture#2 of ? extends com.mycompany.Foo>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Not sure why it worked for Mockito-1.10.x though, literally the same code.

Comment: @Nikolas? What did you learn that [*prompted you to delete*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64024030/3): „*This is not related to Mockito but to the generics*“. Did you stumble on something that established that generics in general are not the root cause of what's reported by the asker? Something that revealed the root cause is something specific to Mockito? Even if you don't know *why* the issue happens, it would still be valuable to know *what* it is that changed your mind. TIA.

Comment: @deduper: I was not sure with the statement so I rather deleted it as long as I have no idea if the Mockito methods parameters have changed over the versions. I will check it out though.

Comment: „*…I have no idea if the Mockito methods parameters have changed over the versions. I will check it out though…*“ — Thanks Nikolas. Yeah. In my experience, Mockito's correct functioning has always been super sensitive to even minor version changes. For example, certain versions of PowerMock will only work with very specific versions of Mockito. That could explain why @ddolce is stuck on such an old version.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this, use:

```java
when(fooMock.doSomething())
        .thenAnswer((Answer<Stream<? extends Bar>>) invocation -> Stream.of(bar1, bar2));
```

This causes no compilation or runtime error.